# Laravel: не могу перенаправить stdout в файл при запуске PHPUnit теста

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Проблема: не могу перенаправить stdout в файл при запуске PHPUnit теста. Как воспроизвести:

### 1. Создать тест

```
php artisan make:test StdoutTest --unit
```

Содержимое теста:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class StdoutTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        die("ok");
    }
}
```

### 2. Запустить тест:

```
php artisan test --filter StdoutTest > dump.log
```

Тест `ok` выводится в консоль, но в файле `dump.log` ничего нет.

- stderr проверял, там пусто

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, нужно использовать опцию `--without-tty`:

```
php artisan test --without-tty --filter StdoutTest > dump.log
```

Ее я нашел в исходный кодах Laravel. Если копнуть чуть глубже, в режиме "tty" вывод осуществлялся в `/dev/tty`. Поэтому перенаправление `stdout` и `stderr` в файл не дает нужного результата.